# Is there an R function that automatically switches from exact to partial matching only if there is no exact match

Tags: r, string

I am looking for an R function (if possible in an existing, well-known package), that matches a string to a pattern and returns i) the first element that matches exactly or, if there are no exact matches ii) the first element that matches partially.

So far I tinkered something using `grep`:

```
data <- c("a", "a b", "c d e", "c d")

my_match <- function(data, pattern) {
  if (pattern %in% data) {
    return(which(pattern == data)[1])
  } else {
    return(grep(pattern, data, fixed = FALSE)[1])
  }
}
```

And some testcases with expected results:

```
my_match(data, "b")
[1] 2
my_match(data, "a")
[1] 1
my_match(data, "a b")
[1] 2
my_match(data, "c")
[1] 3
my_match(data, "e")
[1] 3
my_match(data, "c d")
[1] 4
```

---

- Is there a *preexisting function* that behaves the same way?
- If not: Are there more *succinct* ways to create the same behavior? (my code seems a bit cluttery..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `match` and if no hit `adist` with `which.min`.

```
my_match <- function(data, pattern) {
  i <- match(pattern, data)
  if(is.na(i)) {
    i <- grep(pattern, data)
    i[which.min(adist(pattern, data[i], partial=TRUE))]
  } else i
}

my_match(data, "b")
#[1] 2
my_match(data, "a")
#[1] 1
my_match(data, "a b")
#[1] 2
my_match(data, "c")
#[1] 3
my_match(data, "e")
#[1] 3
my_match(data, "c d")
#[1] 4
my_match(data, "x")
#integer(0)
```

There are many possibilities what could be accepted by *partial matching* which can be adjusted by `costs` in `adist`.